# I can't understand the meaning of this error, Mysql error

Tags: html, mysql

The following code

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts 
                            (parrentid,posttype,name,description,post,
                            posts,author,lastpostauthor,lastpost,locked) 
                    VALUES (':parrentid',':posttype',':name',':description',':post',
                            ':posts',':author',':lastpostauthor',':lastpost',':locked')");
$stmt->bindValue(':parrentid', (int) $parrentID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':posttype', (int) 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', (string) "404", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':description', (string) "404", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':post', (string) $post, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':posts', (int) 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':author', (int) $_SESSION['loggedIn'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':lastpostauthor', (int) 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':lastpost', (int) 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':locked', (int) 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute(); 
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Prints the following error

```
Array ( [0] => HY000 
        [1] => 1366 
        [2] => Incorrect integer value: ':parrentid' for column 'parrentid' at row 1 )
```

What does that mean? I would fix whatever it needs to be fixed if i was able to understand the error. Everything is fine. All parameters are written correctly. And the value of the parrent id is 16, it contains no letters. I don't see why this script would show error.

EDIT: I don't ask for someone to review my code, just tell me the meaning of that error.

Comment: I'm not a PHP guru, but AFAIK using explicit casts in PHP usually is not necessary...so why are you doing it for `$parrentID` ?  Can you share some data with us which might explain what is causing this error?

Comment: what type is the INT you are trying to insert? i mean is it smaller than 0? and did you mark your column to be unsigned when you created the table?

Comment: I tried to wrap my code around the Try/Catch but it kept showing me error, i am not sure how to type it correctly, that's why i printed it the way i shown above. I am programming a forum, and the $parrentID defines on which topic the post is going to be submitted.

Comment: `VALUES (:parrentid, :posttype, :name, :description, :post, :posts, :author, :lastpostauthor, :lastpost, :locked)`

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of the error is that a string literal cannot be converted into an integer value.

---

Just remove the single quotes.

MySQL is seeing this as a string literal:

```
    VALUES (':parrentid',
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There's nothing special about a colon character in a string literal. Remove the single quotes, so that MySQL sees a bind placeholder as a token in the SQL text, rather than seeing a string literal.

```
    VALUES ( :parrentid ,
            ^          ^
```

Comment: Next time you design a database, maybe run a spell checker on the field names.